# How to spy on jQuery's append function Sinon

Tags: javascript, jquery, sinon

I am trying to use `sinon.js` to create a spy on the `jQuery.append` function.

I tried: `var spy = sinon.spy($, "append");` and got the following error:  `TypeError: Attempted to wrap undefined property append as function`.

I then amended to: `var spy = sinon.spy($.fn, "append");` which seems better, but `spy.called` is false.

Comment: I moved some of this question to a new, hopefully clearer question - thanks to all those who tried to help me.  Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17787893/any-better-way-than-setimeout-to-wait-for-asnyc-callbacks-when-testing-javascript

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[`Sinon.spy(object, "method")`](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#sinonspy) expects an object for first parameter, but `$` is a function. You should spy on `$.prototype` like this:

```
var spy = sinon.spy($.prototype, "append");
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RZ825/

or you can just spy single object like this:

```
var spy = sinon.spy($("body"), "append");
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/G5J8H/

Comment: thanks - both $.fn and $.prototype work - I guess because in JavaScript functions are objects.  I think I prefer prototype though.

Comment: what about when inside an async function?  See dited question.

Comment: There's no problem inside async call. See http://jsfiddle.net/BFG7E/ and http://jsfiddle.net/tK2Kz/. Also note `$.fn === $.prototype`.

Comment: apologies again for not being clear - I need to check the spy outside the async function like http://jsfiddle.net/BFG7E/1/

Answer (score 3):

I realize this question is old but I had a similar problem and found a solution to it.

I tried one of the anwsers suggested above.

`var spy = sinon.spy($("body"), "append");`

my version:

`var spy = sinon.spy($("#id"), "function");`

However this did not work and it took me some time to figure out why. Turns out that you need to access the array after the jQuery object.

Like this:

`var spy = sinon.spy($("#id")[0], "function");`

Sinon does not do anything with the jQuery object itself because it can contain multiple values and it doesn't know which one you want (even if there is just one).

PS: I've noticed this does not work for *all* jquery functions. For me it worked for "focus".
PPS: This might not be relevant for this question. But what I've been trying to do is trigger a focus event within karma-runner. So far I've been unsuccesful (click event does work however). I will post a question on StackOverflow for this.

Answer (score 0):

I think You can't spy for jQuery functions - they are binded to every object. It works like this:

- You call method on jQuery object.
- jQuery check for it in own $.fn.
- jQuery check for it in plugins.

And if found - return it. If not - error. Sinon wouldn't work here.

Comment: thanks. - var spy = sinon.spy($.fn, "append"); does seem to work - just not when inside the async function.

Answer (score -1):

You have to spy on `$` and return an object that has the append function as a spy

```
var spy = jasmine.createSpy();
sinon.spy(window, "$").returns({append: spy})
```

Comment: sinon not Jasmine :) - is there something similar?

Comment: @AndreasKöberle it yet confusing actually  - first string is about jasmine spy, second one - about sinon