# Any better way than setTimeout to wait for asnyc callbacks when testing JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sinon

Given this code:

```
showForm = function (url) {
        return $.get(url, function (html) {
             $('body').append();              
        });
 };
```

When using `sinon.js`, `jQuery.mockjax.js` and `expect.js`, I have the following passing test:

```
it("showForm calls jQuery.append", function () {

    $.mockjax({
          url: '/fake'                    
    });

    var spy = sinon.spy($.fn, "append");             
    presenter.showForm('/fake');

    setTimeout(function () { 
        expect(spy.called).to.be.equal(true);
    }, 1000);
});
```

Using the `setTimeout` function to wait on the callback from the asynchronous `$.get` smells bad and it will slow down my test suite if I do too much of it.

However, I feel that the intent is reasonably clear and it does seem to test exactly what I want.

Is there a better way and can you please explain what's going on in your answer?

Comment: Can you make the ajax call async: false?

Comment: thanks, not in this case and not in the mockjax server (that I can see)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass your anonymous function to show form as a parameter and have it called in the callback after the append. To ensure its called you could make it an $.ajax request that covers the error callback as well.

This way it is called exactly when the get request finishes with no excess time or called too early.

```
showForm = function (url, callback) {
        return $.get(url, function (html) {
             $('body').append();   
             if(callback != undefined)
             callback();
        });
 };

it("showForm calls jQuery.append", function () {

    $.mockjax({
          url: '/fake'                    
    });

    var spy = sinon.spy($.fn, "append");

    presenter.showForm('/fake', function (){ 
        expect(spy.called).to.be.equal(true);
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks - I do like this - the only thing I'm not sure about is adding the callback just for testing purposes.  Is this considered good practice?

Comment: Better yet, make the callback optional by testing `if(callback){callback()}`. That way you don't need to modify the production code yet allow test code pass the callback as necessary

Comment: @davy: For the purposes of making the code testable, yes, it's now usually considered good practice. It's considered better to have code that is tested than code that can't be tested even though making the code testable may actually reduce readability a bit.

Comment: @davy, its probably. Put a note in your code to remind you to remove it after and I added slebetman's recommendation so it works with other calls.

Answer (score 1):

You should use sinons [fakeServer](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#fakeServer). This will call your ajax callback immediately, when the `$.ajax` call was made. See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WSGju/1/)

```
before(function(){
  var server = sinon.fakeServer.create();
  server.respondWith('response');
})

it("showForm calls jQuery.append", function () {
    var spy = sinon.spy($.fn, "append");             
    presenter.showForm('/fake');
    server.respond();
    expect(spy.called).to.be.equal(true);
});
```

Comment: thanks, sorry Andreas, this returns false - I'll need to investigate the link fro fakeServer, unless you can spot something obvious?

Comment: Mhmm for some reasons `autoRespond=true` doesn't work here, Updated my answer

Answer (score -1):

Use $.doTimeout plugin

Check the following documentation.

http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-dotimeout-plugin/

Hope this helps